# confusion about JavaFX CSS

Tags: css, javafx

To add a style sheet, I have to do:

```
 Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 400);
 scene.getStylesheets().add("path/stylesheet.css");
```

And to define a style sheet, I have to do:

```
 .custom-button {
-fx-font: 16px "Serif";
-fx-padding: 10;
-fx-background-color: #CCFF99;
}
```

So, does that mean I write this second block of code for 'defining it' on a separate file and save it and then go to my main coding page and write the 'first code block' for adding it and for 'path', I use the filepath of the 'SCC defining code'?

Comment: Basically, yes, though they are not "file paths", they are URLs, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets--).

Comment: James_D: Thank you. so when I write the style sheet like mystyle.css, do I write it on bash terminal? or on Notes? or on Eclipse(I use Eclipse and my laptop is Mac).

Comment: You can edit it wherever you want, but if you are editing the rest of your source files in Eclipse, that would be the obvious place to edit your CSS file(s) too. Not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: James_D: I mean, I'm not talking about editing. I'm talking about writing a complete new CSS block and then saving it. if I do that on Eclipse, do I simply hit 'save' or should I change some settings so that Eclipse will save it as ' FILENAME.css' file instead of ' FILENAME.java'?

Comment: That's one of the things "editing" means. Just create a new file and name it with a `.css` extension.

Comment: James_D: so do I just save it without changing any settings? but wouldn't Eclipse just save it as a typical sourcecode like FILENAME.java? instead of FILENAME.css?

Comment: File -> New -> File. Select the folder and type the file name in. It is not particularly difficult, and seems pretty intuitive to me.

Comment: James_D: alright I'll try that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use your JavaFX CSS in different ways :

1- Add your CSS in external file CSS

2- Add your CSS Inline

both can done programmatically or using FXML file

> 1- programmatically

**A. External File**

**Java Class**

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 400);
scene.getStylesheets().add("path/stylesheet.css");
```

**CSS File (stylesheet.css)**

you can write in your CSS file :

Class selection :

```
 .button {
-fx-font: 16px "Serif";
-fx-padding: 10;
-fx-background-color: #CCFF99;
}
```

ID selection :

```
#my-button{
-fx-font: 16px "Serif";
-fx-padding: 10;
-fx-background-color: #CCFF99;
}
```

setting ID :

```
Button btn = new Button ("custom") ;
btn.setId("my-button");
```

Class custom selection :

```
.mycustom-button{
-fx-font: 16px "Serif";
-fx-padding: 10;
-fx-background-color: #CCFF99;
}
```

setting class selection

```
Button btn = new Button ("custom") ;
btn().clear();
btn.getStyleClass().add("mycustom-button");
```

**Inline**

```
btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkslateblue; -fx-text-fill: white;");
```

> 2- FXML using scene builder

[image]

Comment: @NewLearner If this answers your question, you should [mark it as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).